# rospack became agonizingly slow

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, performance, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I upgraded to Groovy, the rospack command has become really slow. This is true even if have no own package tree, just the distribution itself. The `rospack profile` call runs fast and shows nothing abnormal, but any query takes over a second.
Any ideas what is wrong?

```
$ env | grep ROS_
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros

$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.019685 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.016709   /opt/ros/groovy/share
0.003634 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp
0.003559 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros
0.002273 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/doc
0.002248   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks
0.002195 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/doc/pcl-1.6
0.002161 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/doc/pcl-1.6/tutorials
0.002027 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/doc/pcl-1.6/tutorials/sources
0.000377 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
0.000346   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation
0.000314 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/std_msgs
0.000297 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/sensor_msgs
0.000276 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
0.000263 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core
0.000248 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/OpenCV
0.000244 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/geometry_msgs
0.000232 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/actionlib
0.000218 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/doc/pcl-1.6/tutorials/sources/iros2011
0.000176   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/geometry_experimental
0.000164 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/rospy_tutorials

$ time rospack depends roscpp
cpp_common
rostime
roscpp_traits
roscpp_serialization
genmsg
genpy
message_runtime
rosconsole
std_msgs
rosgraph_msgs
xmlrpcpp

real    0m1.744s
user    0m1.632s
sys 0m0.092s
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53925/rospack-became-agonizingly-slow/) by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1951 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it turns out, rosdep is at least partially responsible. If you are affected, make sure you have upgraded to at least rosdep 0.10.14 and re-run `rosdep update` for a noticeable speedup.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears this slow-down is a a known issue, to quote Brian:

```
Could be because the of the slow-down in rospack with Groovy because of the introduction of a Python interpreter inside it
```

from [here](https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/2) (in an otherwise unrelated xacro issue).

I also noticed this and speed improvements certainly would be welcome.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2013-02-03**:
I did some checking, and the problem is not the Python interpreter per se, but the invocation of `init_rospack_interface` which is part of the rosdep2 package. Incidentally, the rosdep command line tool is really slow as well. Seems to me that rospack just inherited that problem.